# why is the point set $\Sigma_0 \ \subset \Sigma$ dense?

Tags: differential-geometry

Good afternoon, could someone tell me why the set $\Sigma_0 \subset \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is an immersed manifold in a GRW spacetime and $\Sigma_0$ is the tale that contains the points of $\Sigma$ such that these points diagonalize the weingarten operator A[image].

Comment: Did you follow the authors' citation?